# Compactification of Picard variety over normal, projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, picard-group

Let $X$ be a normal, projective, integral variety (over $\mathbb{C}$) and $P$ be the Picard variety parametrizing invertible sheaves on $X$. Does there exist a compactification $\overline{P}$ of $P$ along with an universal family $\mathcal{U}$ defined over $X \times \overline{P}$, flat over $\overline{P}$, parametrizing the space of rank $1$, torsion-free sheaves on $X$ (probably with a fixed Hilbert polynomial)? Any hint/reference will be appreciated.

Comment: For $X$ normal the connected component of ${\rm Pic}_X$ is projective (and over $\mathbf{C}$ it is an abelian variety). This was proved by Grothendieck in FGA, see Kleiman's survey article "The Picard scheme".